# Restrict interpolation to specific mask region

Tags: matlab, image-processing, interpolation

I have a region of an image that I would like to interpolate.  It's surrounded by zeroes, which means that if I attempt to interpolate using MATLAB's built-in `interp2` function, the boundaries of this region will be interpolated with garbage data and compromised.  Is there any known way to, for example, interpolate only a specific set of data points (or even a non-rectangular matrix) and then embed them into a matrix of the correct dimensions? I have a logical mask that can be used, if that helps.

Images, for reference:
[image: lens]
[image: mask]

Answer (score 0):

That's fairly simple to do.  Use the `interp2` command like you would normally use it.  After, you get your interpolated result, use your mask to zero out the garbage locations.  Assuming that `out` is what is returned after `interp2`, and `mask` stores the locations that you want to restrict the interpolation, simply do:

```
maskMatch = cast(mask, class(out)); %// Ensures out and mask are the same type
finalOut = out .* maskMatch;
```

This should zero out those garbage locations while ensuring that those values you want interpolated remain.

---

The above assumes that the output is of the same dimensions as the input.  If you are intending to expand or shrink the image, you can also interpolate the mask as well, then use the same procedure that I just talked about.  As such, simply run `interp2` with your mask so that the dimensions match with `out`, then do the point-by-point multiplication that I talked about above.

Comment: The problem is that interp2 will interpolate the boundaries of the object in the image above with the zeroes around it, which causes distortion.  I'm trying to prevent the background data from being considered during the interpolation process, as if I had a floating blob that I wanted to smooth out.

Comment: @Scott - Do you want to extract just the region then resize the image?

Comment: I suppose that would work- i.e. extract the region with the blob, interpolate, and re-insert it into a resized image.

Comment: @Scott - If that's the case, you can use `imresize` to resize the image to the co-ordinates that you want, then insert it in the right position within the resized matrix

Comment: Any advice on how to extract the region of interest by itself to do processing on?